# why Common Criteria evaluation wont give 100% security

Tags: common-criteria

To understand Common Criteria in better way, could someone tell if system has passed a CC evaluation ie. EAL4, what can we say about the security of this system?

Comment: What would "100% security" even mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is no such thing as 100% security in the first place. There are only ways one can try to achieve the best security for a specific cost and then one needs to be able to handle the remaining risk (or ignore it if it is too unlikely).

Apart from that certifications like Common Criteria only cover a specific part of the system, i.e. the target of evaluation. For example with the recent [ROCA vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROCA_vulnerability) in smartcard chips the product had a very high certification (EAL7) but the specific part of how prime numbers were selected during key generation was not evaluated.

And then, software is complex. And the more complex it is, the harder (i.e. impossible) it is to completely describe what it should do and to create tests which cover every detail and variation and combination of this functionality. And then the auditors need also be able and have the time to understand everything, check everything and not make errors or wrong assumptions themselves. 
For example at EAL7 ([Evaluation Assurance Level 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_Assurance_Level)) formal verification is required which is practically impossible to do with complex systems like firewalls (where you currently get at most EAL4+). And even the first EAL4 evaluation of a product often takes years to complete, in which time usually new features were added to the product already and bugs were fixed - which are not covered by the evaluation but which are needed by the customers.

> ... if system has passed a CC evaluation ie. EAL4, what can we say about the security of this system?

Certification is a best effort but not perfect. It is still way better then no certification and higher assurance levels are better than lower ones since more efforts were done to validate design, functionality, development process etc, i.e. more potential problems are covered. 
So, higher level means more assurance and less bugs. But not necessarily in the whole product but only in the part which got evaluated. Thus you need to get the actual evaluation report to find out what is covered by the evaluation and which parts in which depth.